# Photoshop CC - Create a line path with the path tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path

Is it possible to create a shape path line with the path tool in Photoshop CC? When I create a path and convert it to a shape, it looks something like this.

[image: Example]

It would be great if I could convert the current path to a line shape path with a specified width, the same result as the line tool.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly the same as the line tool, but if you switch from using a Fill to using a Stroke on your shape, you'll get a stroke at whatever width you specify.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wondering how I missed this! I was searching this solution for months!!!
Thanks @Vicki